# How to select option after page loads with prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
<select class="goog-te-combo">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="ja">japan</option>
</select>
```

After page has loaded, I want to select the option whose value is "ja", i want to use prototype to do this automatic, anyone can help me ? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer seems obvious:

```
$$('option[value=ja]').first().selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you assigned an `id` to the `<select>`:

```
(function(element) {
    $A(element.options).each(function(option, index) {
       if ('ja' == option.value)
           element.selectedIndex = index;
    });
})( $('select-id') );
```

To retrieve all `<select>` elements of a given class, do:

```
$$('select.class_name_here').each(function(element) {
    $A(element.options).each(function(option, index) {
       if ('ja' == option.value)
           element.selectedIndex = index;
    });
});
```

<sup>Please refrain from using "denglish" in your code; it makes it look unsexy.</sup>

[Here's a fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2mK4/)

Comment: But i do not assigned an id to the <select>, you know, the select element is from google api

Comment: In Jquery, i can use '$(.class)'